# Shibboleth SP 2 and ADFS sha1 to sha256

Tags: adfs, shibboleth

With shibboleth SP 2, I need to configure ADFS (as IdP) in advance tab SHA-1 algorithm to work fine.

If I configure in ADFS SHA-256 hash algorithm, I get an error in ADFS event log, that SP reponses with SHA-1 algorithm.

My stack OpenSSH, Shibboleth, Debian (Stretch) is very new so it can use SHA-256 algorithm. I install all with debian's repositories with out of the box configuration.

I consulted [this document](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/download/attachments/4358293/ADFS_and_Shib.pdf) and [Microsoft's docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg317734(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking if ADFS can use SHA2?. No, it's either SHA1 or SHA256.

Comment: @nzpcmad I want to use SHA-256 between ADFS and Shibboleth SP. It works only with SHA-1. I think the problem is in shibboleth side.

Comment: Most SAML integrations are SHA1. You'll have to look at the Shibboleth config. to see if you can change to SHA256.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find in the shibboleth [documentation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApplication) those two attributes  :

- signingAlg (URI) (defaults to the specifier for RSA-SHA1)
      An XML Signature signature algorithm specifier for signatures produced by the SP.
- digestAlg (URI) (defaults to the specifier for SHA1)

So I add in my shibboleth2.xml configuration file in the ApplicationDefaults  node :

```
digestAlg="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" 
signingAlg="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"
```

And after that it works with both configuration of ADFS : SHA1 and SHA256.

Comment: So I'm surprised that it works with SHA1 and SHA256 ADFS configuration.